# ACF Relationship - Exclude pages not created by author

Tags: author, advanced-custom-fields

I have pages that I would like to exclude in a ACF relationship field.

My field name is `products` and the following code excludes the pages with id 9, 10 or 11.

```
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=products', 'exclude_id', 10, 3);

function exclude_id ( $args, $field, $post ) {

    $args['post__not_in'] = array( $post, 9, 10, 11 );

    return $args;
}
```

Instead I would like to exclude pages not created by a certain user.

I have user called `collaborator` and want to exclude all pages that dosen't have `collaborator` set as author.

I would rather exclude pages by author name rather than the author id, like

```
author_name('collaborator');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude ALL pages that doese't have 'collaborator' set as author, then you want to exclude all other pages in the site and include all pages of that author minus, maybe, some hand picked pages of that author, then I think you can use this:

```
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=products', 'exclude_id', 10, 3);

function exclude_id ( $args, $post ) { //$field input vriable wasn't neccessary in this function

   $args['post__not_in'] = array( $post, 9, 10, 11 );
   $args['author_name'] = 'collaborator'; // Queries only the collbaroator's posts

   return $args;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.